# Value not captured for SELECT in IONIC4

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

After the value is selected the value shows always empty. Working code in previous version as below. And latest version is also added below.

Am i doing wrong some where ?

IONIC previous version

```
 <div>
    <ion-select>
      <ion-option *ngFor="let city of citys.options" [value]="city"> {{city}}
      </ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </div>
```

IONIC 4

```
 <div>
    <ion-select ngDefaultControl>
      <ion-select-option *ngFor="let city of citys.options" [value]="city"> {{city}}
      </ion-select-option>
    </ion-select>
  </div>
```

Working code if using plain html controls

```
 <div>
    <select ngDefaultControl>
      <option *ngFor="let city of citys.options" [value]="city"> {{city}}
      </option>
    </select>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This importing IonicModule in my components.module.ts made it to work

```
 import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine when I test it - here is what's working for me:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Cities</ion-label>
  <ion-select placeholder="Select One" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity">
    <ion-select-option *ngFor="let city of citys.options">{{city}}</ion-select-option>
  </ion-select>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  You selected: {{selectedCity}}
</ion-item>
```

In ts file:

```
citys = {
    options: ["red", "blue", "yellow"]
  }
```

I would suspect there is something somewhere else that is causing the component to break. Perhaps your `citys` object doesn't contain the data you expect.

Comment: This works for me within the same component. But if i load this control as a child component into a parent component at that time its not working..

Comment: Can you edit your question and add more info about file structure, etc?